# Joomla with pre installed extensions

Tags: php, linux, joomla

i am on Linux VPS . i hvae installed softculous to install joomla using cpanel.
But problem is there are manu extensions like jce editor , community builder etc, which i want to get pre installed with installtion.

Is there any way i can achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Softaculous pro edition allows for the addition of scripts. You'd need to create a package based on the Joomla install with all of the extensions you want included.

http://www.softaculous.com/docs/Category:How_Tos

Are you planning on having users do the installs or is this for your convenience? If it's for you, I would probably just use Akeeba to make a backup of the install you want to use, then use that as the basis for your sites. I have a backup with all the base extensions we use on every site that I start with. It's not one touch but it's still fast and it doesn't cost anything.

Comment: Frankly Akeeba is the best solution you can deploy your Joomla-extension-loaded website extension many times as you want!